# Primefaces 4.0, calendar with timeOnly, onchange event not working expectedly?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I use calendar with timeOnly attribute likes:

```
<p:calendar pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" value="#{data.currentAbsenceData.ABZTIMF}" id="xabsQuickFromTime" onchange="calculateQuickHour();" timeZone="#{data.timeZone}"/>

<p:calendar pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" value="#{data.currentAbsenceData.ABZTIMT}" id="xabsQuickToTime" onchange="calculateQuickHour();" timeZone="#{data.timeZone}"/>

<p:inputText id="xabsQuickHourInput" value="#{data.currentAbsenceData.ABZDAYI}">
```

Javascript code:

```
function calculateQuickHour(){
    console.log("hello _ calculateQuickHour");
    getHourValue('xabsQuickFromTime', 'xabsQuickToTime', 'xabsQuickHourInput');
}
```

Well, I use the slider of the calendar to change the value of its input field, the value of the input field changes perfectly but the javascript function is not called by "onchange" event. This works fine in Primefaces 3.5. So, what is the possible event that should be used in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="calculateQuickHour();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but I should not use ajax in my case, just process in client side.

Comment: okay, I have added global = "false" into p:ajax and it solved my problem. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `org.primefaces.component.calendar.Calendar.EVENT_NAMES` to see all events valid for calendar. If you don't know wich class implements your component have a look in the corresponding `taglib`.

If in some case this doesn't help you can set something invalid and a breakpoint on that particular exception at any time. Just before the exception is thrown there will be some code comparing your invalid value against the valid ones.